# Chart in QML[QChart.js]

Tags: qt, plot, charts, qml

Hi I was looking for chart in QML i found [QChart.js](http://jwintz.me/blog/2014/02/15/qchart-dot-js-qml-binding-for-chart-dot-js) I done the tutorial how import the Chart.js to my project but it doesn't work i get error:

`module "jbQuick.Charts" is not installed`.

When in qml i have:

`import jbQuick.Charts 1.0`

I store my qml files in qrc:

`<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>ActualValues.qml</file>
        <file>LoginScreen.qml</file>
        <file>test.qml</file>
        <file>VoltageHistory.qml</file>
        <file>CurrentIntensityHistory.qml</file>
        <file>VoltagePlot.qml</file>
        <file>CurrentIntensityPlot.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>`

How can I import the chart or which I could use ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to write down the relative or absolute path to QCharts.js in your .pro file

```
QML_IMPORT_PATH += ../path_to_jbQuick_parent_folder
```

The structure of jbQuick folder should look like

```
jbQuick
   -Charts
      -QCharts.js
      -QChart.qml
      -qmldir
      - ...
```

You also have set the path to QCharts.js in your QQmlApplicationEngine instance

```
addImportPath("../path_to_jbQuick_parent_folder")
```

Now, you can import QCharts.js in QML file

```
import jbQuick.Charts 1.0
```

Your question is also answered [here](https://github.com/jwintz/qchart.js/issues/3)

Answer (score 1):

I manage to make it work by adding:

***.pro**

```
QML_IMPORT_PATH += qml
```

**main.cpp**

```
engine.addImportPath(QStringLiteral("jbQuick/Charts"));
engine.addImportPath(QStringLiteral("qml"));
```

Finally, and the most important part: You should copy your folder "jbQuick" (the one which contains the "Charts" subfolder) into your qml compiler folder.

For instance, you should have:

```
WINDOWS -> C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\qml\jbQuick\Charts
MAC-> /Users/XXX/Qt/5.5/clang_64/qml/jbQuick/Charts
```

I hope this helped someone.